# I need a design like that but I'm facing two problems

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need a template for my list view with the following item design

[image]

I've tried some code I found but I did not get the result I need.

```
  <item
    android:bottom="-32dp"
    android:left="-3dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="32dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#fff" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

this is my linearlayout background.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Just use a CardView

Comment: i m a beginner so i would be grateful for you if you make it a detailed answer @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though we can use png for this or  or image to get this . 
but if you really want to do this this drawable  then here the code .

I tried and result was pretty same .

I have created a drawable using two layer list , that contains two different rectangle .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:bottom="10dip">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />

        <size
            android:width="60dp"
            android:height="60dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="20dip">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#800080" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

You can use this in your view as background . I have used this in mine , so i am adding code of my item view .  [image: Here how it looks]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#800080">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_18"
    android:background="@drawable/sample">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Crime Title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_solved"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Crime Date"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/crime_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/crime_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_title" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crime_solved"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/crime_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_solved" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Hope this will be helpful .**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using xml drawable, you can Create a [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch) image for that shape, that might help.

Create that shape in your favourite image-editor and copy that to drawable directory of your project.

1. In Android Studio, right-click the PNG image you'd like to create a NinePatch image from, then click Create 9-patch file.
2. Type a file name for your NinePatch image, and click OK. Your image will be created with the .9.png file extension.
3. Double-click your new NinePatch file to open it in Android Studio. Your workspace will now open.
   The left pane is your drawing area, in which you can edit the lines for the stretchable patches and content area. The right pane is the preview area, where you can preview your graphic when stretched.
4. Click within the 1-pixel perimeter to draw the lines that define the stretchable patches and (optional) content area. Right-click (or hold Shift and click, on Mac) to erase previously drawn lines.
5. When done, click File > Save to save your changes.